# sending emails using templates in Mandrill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, mandrill

I've read through the docs and still am unclear on how to actually use these templates in mandrill.

Currently I have a rails app with the standard Rails mailers (located in: App > views > welcome_mailer > welcome_email.html.erb) being sent through the Mandrill SMTP setup. This is working fine.

Now, I have a template in Mandrill ready to go, now what?

How do I actually use this template, do I need to adjust the code on my app to make a different call, or do I need to do something on the mandrill dashboard to tell it to use the new template instead of the rails version being sent now.

How do I actually use this template?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mandrill_mailer](https://github.com/renz45/mandrill_mailer) gem, inherit your mailer from `MandrillMailer::TemplateMailer` and then send it as usual `InvitationMailer.invite(invitation).deliver`.

Answer (score 3):

Without any gems :

To use mandrill template you first need to create one in your mandrill account and then in your mailer add a correct header which tells the name of the template. Then mandrill will by magic automatically call that template.

Example:

```
# app/mailers
class CardMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "admin@domain.ch"

  def welcome(card)
    mail to:      card.responsable.email,
         from:    "\"Andrey\" <admin@domain.ch>",
         subject: 'Welcome in my website'
    headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = "{\"TYPE\":\"#{card.card_type.name}\"}" # variables
    headers['X-MC-Template'] = "welcome"  # template
    headers['X-MC-AutoText'] = 1 # generate text version
    headers['X-MC-InlineCSS'] = "true" # inline css
  end
end
```

In my case, it uses my "welcome" template. Just use the name of your mandrill template.

As you can see, there are many other headers available. See the full-list [here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21688056-Using-SMTP-Headers-to-customize-your-messages).

**Note** : even if you don't use rails template any more, you still need one in your view.